# BeautifulSoup won't find tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I've read in some HTML from a website that I'm trying to parse into a soup object. After that I have extracted the body of the HTML which I have looked at and seen that it does contain the items that I'm looking for.

The items that I'm looking for are contained inside `<div>` tags, with `class = 'listitem artikal obicniArtikal imaHover-disabled i index'.`

Now I'm trying to do do:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.olx.ba/pretraga?trazilica=golf+2', timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') 
body = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'rezultatipretrage'})

all_items = body.find_all('div', class_='listitem artikal obicniArtikal imaHover-disabled i index') 
print(all_items)
```

`all_items` returns an empty list even though the tags are present in the `body`.

I would be sincerely grateful if anybody would tell me what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select tag that contains all specified classes, you can use BeautifulSoup's `select()` method.

`soup.select('div#rezultatipretrage div.listitem.artikal.obicniArtikal.imaHover-disabled.i.index')` will select all `<div>` tags with class `listitem artikal obicniArtikal imaHover-disabled i index` that are under `<div>` tag with `id="rezultatipretrage"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.olx.ba/pretraga?trazilica=golf+2', timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

all_items = soup.select('div#rezultatipretrage div.listitem.artikal.obicniArtikal.imaHover-disabled.i.index')

for item in all_items:
    print(item.p.text)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Will print:

```
VW Golf 6 2.0 TDI XENON-NAVI-KAMERA-KOZA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Golf 5 2.0 tdi. Sport line. bosch dizne
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VW GOLF 7 2.0 TDI DSG , ID: 086
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VW GOLF 5 2.0 TDI, 2005 god. Registrovan
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Golf 5 2.0 DIZEL SDI TEK REGISTROVAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Volkswagen Golf 6 2.0 TDI GTI-GTD-R LINE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VW GOLF 5,2.0 TDI,103 KW,04 G.P,6 BRZ.MOTOR U KVARU
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Golf 6 2.0 TDI
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VW GOLF 7 2.0tdi 110kw 150ks mod 2014g
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Golf 2 1.6Dizel reg do 12 2018god
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VW Golf 2.0 ekstra stanje
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Golf 2 DIZEL 4 VRATA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Golf 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VW GOLF 5 V 2.0 TDI CLIMATRONIC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is the solution to the problem. Thank you very much!